# how to create package in jade?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS site guides how to create package in fuerte which i think is old version, i've installed ROS Jade and want to create a package in JADE workspace ,with this distribution, can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228014/how-to-create-package-in-jade?/) by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-02**:
In future questions, if you have a question about a tutorial please provide a link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you were referencing this tutorial, http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage , then you have to make sure you have 'catkin' selected, rather than 'rosbuild' (this option is located right below 'Next Tutorial: Building a ROS package').

---

Originally posted by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) with karma: 40 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0